# Where to put the business logic for updating tables?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, model-view-controller, model, business-logic

Where would I put the CreateOrder () business logic?

```
class Order // this is an entity model for DbContext
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public String name { set; get; }
}

public void CreateOrder(Details details)
{
    // set up Order fields

    database_name.Order.Add(order);
}
```

Controller would call `obj.CreateOrder(details);`

Would it go in a different class in the App_Code folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question has been debated quite a bit.  It all depends on how you want to structure your application.  You can see multiple viewpoints to this question here: [MVC: Where to put business logic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18563229/mvc-where-to-put-business-logic)

I have seen applications where the CreateOrder method would be part of the Model (in this case the Order class).

I have also seen a lot of applications that keep the Model as clean as possbile (POCO classes, as you currently have) and would put the CreateOrder method in a Business Layer that handles any business specific rules, and another CreateOrder method in a Data Layer that would handle actually commiting it to the database.

Some designs work better for small applicaitons, while others work better for more complex applicaitons.